# How to validate a LinkedIn public profile url

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to validate a link to make sure that it is pointing to a LinkedIn public profile page in PHP.

I have a website and I would like my users to be able to share their LinkedIn profile in their profile on my website.

Comment: I created the class to [validate the linkedin url](https://github.com/gchokeen/linkedinURLValidator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this where `$username` is the linked-in username.
You also can set $profileurl directly to the link given and verify with `str_pos` that is starts with http://www.linkedin.com/in/

```
$profileurl = "http://www.linkedin.com/in/".$username;

$fp = curl_init($profileurl);
$response = curl_exec($fp);
$response_code = curl_getinfo($fp, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$validprofile = ($response_code == 200);
```

`$validprofile` will be a boolean indicating if the profile is valid.

Comment: don't forget `/in/username` is only if the user has chosen a custom url.  Otherwise it looks more like `/pub/fname-lname-etc/4/72/8a0`

Answer (score 6):

I've found a number of ways the profile url can look like:

```
http://uk.linkedin.com/pub/some-name/1/1b3/b45/
http://nl.linkedin.com/pub/other-name/11/223/544
http://www.linkedin.com/in/aname/
http://www.linkedin.com/in/another-name
http://linkedin.com/in/name
http://nl.linkedin.com/in/name
http://nl.linkedin.com/in/name/
```

I've used this regex to describe it:

```
^https?://((www|\w\w)\.)?linkedin.com/((in/[^/]+/?)|(pub/[^/]+/((\w|\d)+/?){3}))$
```

It is not strict-strict but it got me home.

**edit**
- Added https support

Comment: I'm seeing a form that looks like `https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=12345678` now.

Comment: it wont work if url is like

        http://linkedin.com/in/namehttp:
        http://linkedin.com/in/namewww.
        http://linkedin.com/in/namehttps:

Comment: I mean what if user puts multiple http: or www. or https:

Answer (score 6):

Following expression will help you with all patterns:

```
((https?:\/\/)?((www|\w\w)\.)?linkedin\.com\/)((([\w]{2,3})?)|([^\/]+\/(([\w|\d-&#?=])+\/?){1,}))$
```

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oT7iM2/5

Comment: LinkedIn profile URLs can contain non-latin characters, and can be provided to you both as plain text or URL-encoded by the user. I.e. `https://www.linkedin.com/in/святий-миколай-bbc1aaa` or `https://linkedin.com/in/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9-bbc1aaa` In both these cases this expression will fail. It works well for latin use cases though. For the url-encoded URLs, simply adding the % to the character class [\w|\d-&#?=] can help.

Answer (score 4):

I use another regular expression more permisive:

`^(http(s)?:\/\/)?([\w]+\.)?linkedin\.com\/(pub|in|profile)`

It includes URLs without squeme and all samples from other answers. You can make any variation here http://regex101.com/r/vE8tV7

Comment: This breaks for search urls like http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/+/semnani/us-49-greater-los-angeles-area

Comment: What about this one: https://regex101.com/r/vE8tV7/38  Only pub is missing as until now, I haven't found any url like that.

Answer (score 3):

This is tested regular expression that I use on my website. I fit all the variations that currently exist.

```
var linkedin=/(https?)?:?(\/\/)?(([w]{3}||\w\w)\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

Comment: How can you make http/https/ftp protocol optional in this? what if someone just enters www.linkedin.com/their-profile-name, without http. Apart from that this works.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal You can use any URL combination and you will get right result. I change a bit code but pattern is the same. If you understand regex, you will se that work with or without http, https and www

Answer (score 2):

There a very nice examples on the developer API pages http://developer.linkedin.com/

This http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile-plugin could be what your looking for.

Comment: FYI: URL of developer page is now invalid

Comment: Downvoted for invalid link.

Answer (score 2):

This covers most LinkedIn profile URLs (Javascript RegEx):

- http://www.linkedin.com/in/username
- https://www.linkedin.com/in/username
- http://linkedin.com/in/username
- https://linkedin.com/in/username
- http://www.linkedin.com/mwlite/in/username
- https://www.linkedin.com/mwlite/in/username
- http://linkedin.com/mwlite/in/username
- https://linkedin.com/mwlite/in/username
- http://www.linkedin.com/m/in/username
- https://www.linkedin.com/m/in/username
- http://linkedin.com/m/in/username
- https://linkedin.com/m/in/username

```js
// Generic RegEx exact match validator
export const isRegexExactMatch = (value, regexp) => {
  const res = value.match(regexp);
  return res && res[0] && res[0] === res.input;
};

const isLinkedinProfileUrl = (value) => {
  const linkedInProfileURLRegExp =
    '(https?:\\/\\/(www.)?linkedin.com\\/(mwlite\\/|m\\/)?in\\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\\/?)';
  return !!isRegexExactMatch(value, linkedInProfileURLRegExp);
};
```

Comment: is show me error when I put it in my code, I think you add extra "/" updated regex it ```/https?:\/\/(www.)?linkedin.com\/(mwlite\/|m\/)?in\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\/?/```

Answer (score 1):

I have this for all kind of URLs for Linkedin for javascript

```
export const isValidLinkedinUrl = (url) => {
  return /(https?:\/\/(www.)|(www.))?linkedin.com\/(mwlite\/|m\/)?in\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\/?/.test(url);
};
```

only RegExp

```
/(https?:\/\/(www.)|(www.))?linkedin.com\/(mwlite\/|m\/)?in\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\/?/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to ensure that the link matches the form taken by linkedin public profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I've simply used the following regex:

```
http(s)?:\/\/([w]{3}\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]{5,30})\/?
```

According to the latest Linkedin documentation custom profile url can have 5-30 letters or numbers.

It works for the following list of url:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/in/your-profile-5-30-length/
https://linkedin.com/in/your-profile-5-30-length/
http://www.linkedin.com/in/your-profile-5-30-length/
http://linkedin.com/in/your-profile-5-30-length/
```

Comment: The documentation still says this, but it is outdated or inaccurate. https://linkedin.com/in/eee https://linkedin.com/in/abc

Comment: Note that `https://www.linkedin.com/in/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2-45456994/` is valid, which (since most systems will parse the UTF-8 cyrillic unicode chars as, say, %NN chars) is way more than 30 chars, or even 90 chars.