# Linkedin link verification

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a registration form asking for linked in URL and other user details. I have to check the Linked in profile existence with the URL entered by the user to allow registration. How to check the profile existence in Linkedin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450403/how-to-validate-a-linkedin-public-profile-url . I would open the url and for instance check if the meta tag `<meta name="globalTrackingAppName" content="profile">` is in the returned content, that would make you relatively sure that this is a true profile url.

Comment: response code is 0 always

Comment: AS far as I know 0 is not a valid http response code, this means that your check is not working, can you add your programming language + a snipped of code?

Comment: checking with the code reffered by you, with my linked in username