# Getting invalid Linkedin profile url from a huge dataset

Tags: python, http, request, linkedin-api

So I have a list of LinkedIn profile urls and I am trying to fetch profile which are invalid "ERROR(404)" using python

Tried python request but it results status code 999 for valid profiles also.

Is there any different approach to handle this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code 999 is returned for websites that doesn't allow scanning (including LinkedIn). Source: [https://hexometer.com/http-status-codes/#:~:text=Status%20code%20999%20%2D%20a%20non,which%20do%20not%20permit%20scanning](https://hexometer.com/http-status-codes/#:%7E:text=Status%20code%20999%20%2D%20a%20non,which%20do%20not%20permit%20scanning).

Try checking LinkedIn API to find if there's something that might achieve what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/methods?view=li-lms-2022-07

Otherwise, if you just want to validate the url, there's a thread about a PHP solution: [How to validate a LinkedIn public profile url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450403/how-to-validate-a-linkedin-public-profile-url)